# Inserting code with XJC+xsd+jxb using the options " -Xinject-code -extension "

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, extending

Im' trying to use the extension **"-Xinject-code"** of **xjc** to add some code to my generated classes. For the following simple xsd schema...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="MyList" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="MyItem" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="MyItem">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

.. I've associated the following binding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:ci="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="ci "
jxb:version="2.1"
>

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='MyItem']">
        <ci:code>
            @Override
            public String toString() { return this.getName();}
        </ci:code>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

Running xjc produces the following output:

```
$ xjc -target 2.1 -verbose -Xinject-code -extension -d . -p generated -b test.jxb test.xsd 
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[INFO] generating code
unknown location

generated/MyItem.java
generated/MyList.java
generated/ObjectFactory.java
```

but the file 'generated/MyItem.java' doesn't contain the new method "toString". How should I fix this ? What is that message "unknown location" ?

Note:

```
$ xjc -version
xjc 2.2.4
```

**EDIT:**

changing xsd:element to xsd:complexType does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


<xs:complexType name="MyItemType">
  <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType> 

  <xs:element name="MyList" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MyItem" type="MyItemType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:ci="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/plugin/code-injector"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="ci "
jxb:version="2.1"
>

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="/xs:schema/xs:complexType[@name='MyItemType']">
        <ci:code>
            @Override
            public String toString() { return this.getName();}
        </ci:code>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

I can now see the code in file "generated/MyItemType.java"

```
$ tail  generated/MyItemType.java


            @Override
            public String toString() { return this.getName();}

}
```

but how can I tell xjc to generate the code without changing the xsd file ?

Answer (score 6):

Please try `/xs:schema/xs:element[@name='MyItem']/xs:complexType`.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and your answer is the correct solution. Thanks!