# Is there a way to customize your getter from a jaxb unmarshalling?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a schema where I would like to customize the resulting getters from its unmarshalling.

What kind of custom binding would allow me to do that? 
An example would be a getter where I initialize the object with some default values before returning it, in the case that the object is NULL.

eg

`public smapleType getSampleObject() {
    (if sampleObject == NULL)
         sampleObject.setField(0);
    return sampleObject;
}`

Is there a way to get JAXB to generate a customized getter like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating subclasses of your domain classes and ObjectFactory - more details here https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Adding_behaviors.html

Comment: Provided link is broken, check [this one](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#compiling-xml-schema-adding-behaviors)

Answer (score 0):

Since you name this `NULL` thingy *an example*, I assume you're interested in a more general approach.

As cases like in your example are very specific, there's no universal customization for that. The closed would probably be the [`-Xinject-code`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262289/inserting-code-with-xjcxsdjxb-using-the-options-xinject-code-extension) plugin.

If you want deep customization of the generated code, then a hardcore way of [writing an XJC plugin](https://jaxb.java.net/plugin.html) is probably the only one generic enough. But it's not quite easy.