# Need to add a method to JAXB class. How? Or should I?

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb, wadl

I use JAXB to generate POJOs from a WADL xsd. I downloaded the xsd directly from W3C. However, I'd like one of my POJOs to have a helper method that allows me to recurse through it, like so:

```
public Stream<WadlResource> flattenPath() {
    return Stream.concat(
        Stream.of(this), 
        this.methodOrResource.stream()
                .filter(WadlResource.class::isInstance)
                .map(WadlResource.class::cast)
                .flatMap(WadlResource::flattenPath) // recursion here
            );
}
```

Notice the use of `this`. This method is the only way I've seen of recursing with a stream.

So my question is: How do I add this method so that it is generated along with the xsd? Is that good practice? Or should I just generate the code once, add the method, and check it into my repo (which DOESN'T seem like good practice). TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that good practice?

This is subjective. I normally do not do this. I prefer to have the schema-derived classes as simple DTO without any business logic.

> How do I add this method so that it is generated along with the xsd?

You can inject code with the Code Injector Plugin. Please see the following question:

[Inserting code with XJC+xsd+jxb using the options " -Xinject-code -extension "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262289/inserting-code-with-xjcxsdjxb-using-the-options-xinject-code-extension)

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how I would rewrite me recursive method in a utility class?

Comment: @user1660256 You recursively call the method of the utility class. This is a different question, please ask it separately.